# Working with Entity framework with multiple databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am very new to Entity Framework. I need to do something like below;

When page loads it will display data from **table1** in **database1**
depending on the data select from the first page it has to connect to different databases (These databases has same names. But can have slight changes).
I already have a way get the connections to those different DBs.

I have no idea where should I start. Please guide me. It is good if you can provide me with basic level information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a separate instance of database context for each database and specify connection string as a constructor parameter

```
var dbContext = new MyDbContext("<connection string>")
```

if there is fixed list of connection strings then they can be stored in config file and used by name like

```
var dbContext = new MyDbContext("Name=FirstDb")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the Connection String to the `DbContext` constructor:

```
var db1 = new MyContext(connectionString1);
var db2 = new MyContext(connectionString2);
```

and in the context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string cs) : base(cs) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need 2 models or context if you not using entity model.
if your about to use the entity model then the wizard will ask for connection string, and you will create 2 model with 2 connection strings.

i prefer the model because it easy and you the changes in the database will handle your code in one update click